# writing text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write a text file in matlab and getting problem with printing of symbols (\, %%, %\ => etc).

How can I do it.

Its sample from atlatex file.

I just want to print it (on a file)

```
%% Basierend auf einer TeXnicCenter-Vorlage von Tino Weinkauf.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% HEADER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
% Alternative Optionen:
%   Papiergröße: a4paper / a5paper / b5paper / letterpaper / legalpaper / executivepaper
% Duplex: oneside / twoside
% Grundlegende Fontgrößen: 10pt / 11pt / 12pt


%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-Schriftart für nicht-englische Texte


%% Packages für Grafiken & Abbildungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
%\usepackage{subfig} %%Teilabbildungen in einer Abbildung
%\usepackage{pst-all} %%PSTricks - nicht verwendbar mit pdfLaTeX

%% Beachten Sie:
%% Die Einbindung einer Grafik erfolgt mit \includegraphics{Dateiname}
%% bzw. über den Dialog im Einfügen-Menü.
%% 
%% Im Modus "LaTeX => PDF" können Sie u.a. folgende Grafikformate verwenden:
%%   .jpg  .png  .pdf  .mps
%% 
%% In den Modi "LaTeX => DVI", "LaTeX => PS" und "LaTeX => PS => PDF"
%% können Sie u.a. folgende Grafikformate verwenden:
%%   .eps  .ps  .bmp  .pict  .pntg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For special characters you usually use `\` backslash. For `%` you simply use `%%` in the format string:

```
fprintf( 1, '%%\n'); % print '%'
```

see documentation of [formatting strings in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) for more details.

**EDIT :**

If you wish to print many chars, you may use

```
n = 10; % number of % to be printed
fprintf( 1, [repmat('%', 1, 2*n), '\n']);
```

Comment: and if I want to print commented lines (%%%%%%%%%%%%%, )then??

Comment: @user31177 - to print 10 such symbols you can use `fprintf(1, [ repmat('%', 1, 2*10 ),'\n'] );`

Comment: @user31177 You can also use `char('%' * ones(1, 2*10)))` instead of `repmat(...)`.